# Probability problem involving random strings

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose we pick a bit string of length 4 at random, all bit strings equally likely. Consider the following
events:

$E_1$: the string begins with 1.

$E_2$: the string ends with 1.

$E_3$: the string has exactly two 1’s

Find $Pr(E_2 | E_1 ∩ E_3)$

My reasoning was that $Pr(E_1) = .5$

$Pr(E_3) =$ $3\choose1$$.5^2*.5^1 = .375$

$Pr(E_1∩E_3) = .5 * .375 = .1875$

$Pr(E_2 | E_1 ∩ E_3) = \frac{Pr(E_2) * Pr(E_1∩E_3)}{Pr(E_1∩E_3)}$

$Pr(E_2 | E_1 ∩ E_3) = \frac{.5 * .1875}{.1875} = .5$

However the correct answer is $\frac{1}{3}$. I was wondering where the flaw in my logic is here?

Comment: There is a mistake of notation in the calculation of the probability of $E_1\cap E_3$, but the answer turns out to be right. The probability of $E_2\cap(E_1\cap E_3)$, which is what belongs in the numerator, is wrong, it should be $1/16$. We don't multiply, since we do not have independence.

Comment: Note that the answer $1/3$ is "obvious." We are told the first is $1$, and that there are two $1$'s. Given this information, the other $1$ is equally likely to be in positions $2$, $3$, or $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake:

$$P(E_2|E_1 \cap E_3)=\frac{P(E_2 \color\red{\cap} E_1 \cap E_3)}{P(E_1 \cap E_3)}$$

---

There are $16$ strings, out of which, $8$ end with one.

Therefore $P(E_2)=\frac{8}{16}$

---

There are $16$ strings, out of which, $3$ start with one and have exactly $2$ ones.

Therefore $P(E_1 \cap E_3)=\frac{3}{16}$

---

There are $16$ strings, out of which, $1$ starts with one, end with one and has exactly $2$ ones.

Therefore $P(E_2 \cap E_1 \cap E_3)=\frac{1}{16}$

---

Finally:

$$P(E_2|E_1 \cap E_3)=\frac{P(E_2 \cap  E_1 \cap E_3)}{P(E_1 \cap E_3)}=\frac{\frac{1}{16}}{\frac{3}{16}}=\frac13$$

Comment: thanks for the reply! although my $P(E_1 \cap E_3)$ does equal $\frac{3}{16}$. I just wrote it in decimal form

Comment: @stumped: Sorry, extended the answe to include your mistake (in red).